# Scaling of resistance in different dimensions

Tags: electrical-resistance, scaling

Reading a [pedagogical article](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9907002) by Steve Girvin on the quantum Hall effect, I noticed a result that in principle I have known for a long time, but I had never actually noticed.

In $\rm 1D$, resistance scales linearly with length, $L$, $R = \rho L$, whereas in $\rm 2D$ it scales like $R = \rho$, and in $\rm 3D$ like $R = \rho / L$. This can be summarised in the paper's *Eq. 1.3* :

$$R = \rho L^{2-d}$$

where $d$ is the dimension of the conductor.

In particular this relation singles out the importance of $d = 2$.

**My question :**

Whether *Eq. 1.3* is simply an empirical finding (i.e. we know the scaling in different physical dimensions, and notice it can be fitted by this form), or whether there is a theoretical explanation for it - in particular for the presence of the "2" in the exponent. As a further point, does this equation hold for $d=4$, and higher dimensions in general?

Comment: This is true only when the lengths are greater than the coherence lengths. It is certainly not true in quantum point contacts, see [Conductance quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductance_quantum)

Answer (score 1):

One might argue as follows. The resistance $R$ should be proportional to
$$R \sim \frac{\ell}{A_d}$$
where $\ell$ is the length of the wire and $A_d$ the cross-section area in $d$ dimensions. Let $L$ be some length scale in $d$-dimensional space. Then, $A_d \sim L^{d-1}$. (E.g. in $d=3$ the cross-section surface scales as $A_2 \sim L^2$.) The length of the wire scales as $\ell \sim L$. It follows
$$R \sim \frac{L}{L^{d-1}} = L^{2-d}$$
as desired.